# Loop for many letter inputs

Tags: java, while-loop, try-catch, java.util.scanner

If the user accidentaly gives wrong input (letter), I want the program to loop again and again until the correct input is given, but with the below code I have some errors. Any ideas?

```
catch (InputMismatchException e) {
      input.nextLine();
      while (!input.hasNextInt()) {
            System.out.print("Enter the number of people in the circle: ");
            numberOfPeople = input.nextInt();
      }
}
```

The error output:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException at 
java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:840) at 
java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1461) at 
java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2091) at 
java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2050)
```

Comment: You are looping inside the catch. Pro-tip: You only enter this catch on the first matching error in a try. You'll exit this catch on the next one (or if you succeed, of course). Write a better flow of control.

Comment: @JimDim that means you are not passing an int to your scanner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [the API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/InputMismatchException.html):

> Thrown by a Scanner to indicate that the token retrieved does not
>   match the pattern for the expected type, or that the token is out of
>   range for the expected type.

This is caused because it's not reading the correct type.

I suggest you to use [Scanner#hasNextInt()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextInt%28%29) and to do something like this (Note that there is no usage of try-catch blocks):

```
if (input.hasNextInt()) {
    numberOfPeople = scanner.nextInt();
}
else {
    input.next();
    continue;
}
```

Why we use `next()`? Because of what the Java docs says about [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html):

> When a scanner throws an InputMismatchException, the scanner will not
>   pass the token that caused the exception, so that it may be retrieved
>   or skipped via some other method.

Answer (score 0):

Something like below can be done

```
for(int i=1;i<n;i++)
{
try
{
//code for taking the input from user
}
catch(InputMismatchException exception)
{
 //Equivalently keeping the same value of i 
--i;
}

}
```